# 404 NOT FOUND with LARAVEL6

Tags: php, laravel

i have a problem while passing a variable into the URL , the route exists but still" 404 NOT FOUND" .

**Form :**

```
<form action="/rdv_{{$go->ID}}" method="post" role="form" data-aos="fade-up">
       @csrf
     <input placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
     <input placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone " type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" 
      id="subject" /> 
    <div id="buttons"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Prendre un rendez-vous </button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

**Controller :rendezv.php:**

```
 public function rdv ($ID) {

        $nm=request('email');
        $tel=request('tel');
        $ID=request('{{$go->ID}}');

        $doctor=doc::findOrFail($ID);
        $rdv = new rendezvous() ;
        $rdv->Email=$nm;
        $rdv->Numéro_de_téléphone=$tel;
        $rdv->IDD=$doctor->ID;
        $rdv-> save();
        return redirect('/index') ; 
     }

}
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('/rdv_{ID}','rendezv@rdv');
```

The error is only "404 | Not Found". When I click the button for " Prendre un rendez-vous" the address became: " http:/ /localhost:8000/ rdv_1032569" and the error is probably there.

Comment: Do you have `Route::get('/index', ...` in your routes? Also you can use `dd(..);` in each line to display something in browser. For example check your $ID after $ID = ... by `dd($ID):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-modified the code as follows:

View: I updated the form action and added an hidden input field which has the value "$go-ID".

```
<form action="/rdv" method="post" role="form" data-aos="fade-up">
       @csrf
     <input placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" />
     <input placeholder="Votre numéro de téléphone " type="text" class="form-control" name="tel" id="subject" /> 
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="goID" value="{{$go->ID}}" />
    <div id="buttons"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Prendre un rendez-vous </button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Controller: I assumed that $go->ID in the view is the same as $doctor->ID in the controller. So, I assigned the value of $rdv->IDD to be $ID;

public function rdv () {

```
    $nm=request('email');
    $tel=request('tel');
    $ID=request('goID');

    $rdv = new rendezvous() ;

    $rdv->Email=$nm;
    $rdv->Numéro_de_téléphone=$tel;
    $rdv->IDD=$ID;

    $rdv-> save();

    return redirect('/index') ; 
 }
```

Route: I removed '_{ID}' from the route.

```
Route::post('/rdv','rendezv@rdv');
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is most likely from this `$doctor=doc::findOrFail($ID);`
If there's no doc model with the ID specified, laravel automatically returns a 404.

To change this behaviour, use `find()` and handle the return manually e.g

```
  $doctor=doc::find($ID);

if(!$doctor) {
// return here
}
```

Comment: No is not working , always 404 not found :(

Answer (score 0):

Change route 
`Route::post('/rdv/{ID}','rendezv@rdv')->name('rdv');` 
and form route 
`actions="{{ route('rdv', [$go->ID]) }}"`

Comment: same problem :( always with 404 not found but the url change that mean the rout exists